# Why does CMake not respect LIBRARY_PATH and CPATH

Tags: linux, cmake

I'm using CMake on a HPC system that uses modules. Those modules usually set `LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPATH` so one can simply include headers and link against libraries without additional `-L` or `-I`.

However when using CMake those libraries must be found by CMake. I would expect, that `LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPATH` were automatically considered by CMake and captured in e.g. `CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH` but they are not.

Is there any reasoning why this was (not) done?

Wouldn't it be a good idea (for now manually, later automatically by CMake) to append `LIBRARY_PATH` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPATH` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH`?

Comment: There are endless problems with the way the tool configures projects. The one that baffles me is CMake does not honor `CFLAGS` or `CXXFLAGS`.

Comment: CMake honor CFLAGS (first time) unless you defined CMAKE_CFLAGS cf https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/envvar/CFLAGS.html

Answer (score -1):

> Is there any reasoning why this was (not) done?
>
> Wouldn't it be a good idea (for now manually, later automatically by CMake) to append `LIBRARY_PATH` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_LIBRARY_PATH` and `CPATH` to `CMAKE_SYSTEM_INCLUDE_PATH`?

There is another view that having your build depend on environment variables results in unreliable builds. [From GNU Make manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Environment):

> It is not wise for makefiles to depend for their functioning on environment variables set up outside their control, since this would cause different users to get different results from the same makefile. This is against the whole purpose of most makefiles.

Comment: But CMake has already depended on some environment variables, like `CXXFLAGS`. So adding dependency on another one (`LIBRARY_PATH`) shouldn't harm a lot. Note, that dependency is only for configuration stage. Makefiles created don't depend on these variables.

Comment: It's a pleasant thought to not need to rely on environment variables as part of the build process, but sometimes it's not an option as the OP said. The alternative is to always install all libraries in the system's /usr/ directory, but not everyone will have access to do that, and in addition to that, there's compatibility problems with what is already there (ironically, making your build process depend on what's already on the OS, and causing different users to get different results); avoiding different results for different users is hard and Makefiles don't solve that problem on their own.

Comment: @jrh Most makefiles accept `CPPFLAGS`, `LDFLAGS` and friends from the environment, sure. But that is not a given, a makefile must explicitly cater for that. The main idea is that makefile assignments override environment variables, but you can override makefile assignments explicitly on make command line. So that it is explicit that your override something in the makefile, rather than your environment variables changed, you did not notice, and now the build is funny.