# how to make INCLUDE_PATH of cmake to take effect in each project without modifying CMakelists.txt

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I have learned that in clion ,we  can use
 include_directories(the path to header file)
to include the file.

but g++/gcc has
CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH/C_INCLUDE_PATH,
both of which can be searched when you run
g++ hello.cpp
or
gcc hello.c

But in clion we need to write an extra file:CMakelists.txt.

Is there a way to set the "include directory" globally like g++/gcc?

Many thanks~

Comment: CMake does not support setting `CPATH`, refer: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50346194/why-does-cmake-not-respect-library-path-and-cpath).

Comment: Do you want to globally include directories in `CMakeLists.txt` then use [include_directories](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/include_directories.html).

Comment: I want there's no need to write "include_directories" in clion again

Comment: In short: no. If you don't want to modify your project, create a wrapper `CMakeList.txt` for your project with `include_directories` set.